# Arbitrary loopback ip addresses besides 127.0.0.1

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ip, localhost

I am developing a web app that has to produce different output based on ip. For testing and during development it would help a lot if I could have more loopback ip addresses besides 127.0.0.1. Is there a way to create (and latter destroy) these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit /etc/network/interfaces

add the following at the bottom of the file

```
auto lo:0
iface lo:0 inet static
address 127.0.0.2
netmask 255.0.0.0
```

Documentation on interfaces file can be found here : http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man5/interfaces.5.html

The definition above firstly tells the system to automatically bring the new lo:0 virtual interface (alias) up when the system starts. Then it sets interface lo:0 (bound to the loopback interface) to be a static address. The last two lines set the address and the netmask.

After you have added the above you will need to restart networking

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

or reboot the computer.

Answer (score 1):

The whole `127.0.0.1/8` address space is reserved for loopback addresses. So you can use any address from `127.0.0.1` up to `127.255.255.254`.

Comment: +1, good to know fact. However, I tried http://127.0.0.5/ with my browser and I get *(111) Connection refused* error. So, I guess I should try the method @Sam [suggests](http://serverfault.com/a/579443/25163).

Comment: They're reserved, but not available for applications unless the interface(s) are added. see http://askubuntu.com/questions/444124/how-to-add-a-loopback-interface/444128#444128. For contrast, on Windows, the full range is bindable without manually adding more interfaces.